# max value from specified column in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

We need a maximum value from a numpy array with 3 columns.

Sample, i need the maximum value per array of the last column.
In this case the result is: 57.65048981 for the first array, 58.3501091 for the second and 56.86465836 for the third. How to get these 3 values in an array included by the 2 2 values in the columns before?

```
[array([[ 402.        ,  242.        ,   57.65048981],
   [ 401.        ,  243.        ,   56.32482529]]), 
array([[ 356.        ,  257.        ,   53.3116188 ],
   [ 355.        ,  258.        ,   53.69690704],
   [ 356.        ,  258.        ,   57.52435684],
   [ 355.        ,  259.        ,   56.98838806],
   [ 356.        ,  259.        ,   57.81959152],
   [ 354.        ,  260.        ,   55.90369415],
   [ 355.        ,  260.        ,   58.14822769],
   [ 356.        ,  260.        ,   58.3501091 ],
   [ 354.        ,  261.        ,   55.1479187 ],
   [ 355.        ,  261.        ,   58.20180893],
   [ 354.        ,  262.        ,   54.5345459 ]]), 
array([[ 386.        ,  260.        ,   56.86465836],
   [ 386.        ,  261.        ,   54.28659439],
   [ 386.        ,  259.        ,   56.53445435]])]
```

The result of this should be:

```
[[402, 242, 57.65048981],
[356 ,260, 58.3501091],
[386 ,260, 56.86465836]]
```

Comment: Is that list of numpy arrays?

Comment: The sample output doesn't match your description. Which one is wrong?

Comment: Now its corrected thanks!

Comment: I assume the bottom right value should be 56.86465836?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's an error in your "results"

```
np.array([arr[np.argmax(arr[:, 2]), :] for arr in arrays])
```

returns

```
array([[ 402.        ,  242.        ,   57.65048981],
       [ 356.        ,  260.        ,   58.3501091 ],
       [ 386.        ,  260.        ,   56.86465836]])
```

Comment: Quick that was - was about to post `[arr[arr[:, -1].argmax(), :].tolist() for arr in arrays]` - this will give list of lists as the OP wanted.